# Python pdb command history not working on Windows

Tags: python, pdb

I'm using Windows 7 + Cygwin + Python 2.6 + cmd prompt. Since yesterday, command line history stopped working with pdb. I used the following lines in my python code for interactive debugging.

```
import pdb
pdb.set_trace()
```

Earlier, I was able to recall the command history with up arrow but it stopped working recently. I remember adding a few cygwin packages around the time it stopped working. If there's some easy/obvious way to find what caused the error please advise or else I'll try rolling back whatever I've installed.

Comment: Are you in fact using cmd prompt? Or rather bash?

Comment: Are you using Cygwin's Python, or a native Windows Python installation?

Comment: native Windows Python installation

Comment: Then it is indeed very strange why this should be influenced by changes to the Cygwin installation, they should be entirely unrelated. Have you added Cygwin's bin folder to cmd's %PATH% setting?

Comment: Thanks for helping. Yes, python.exe & cygwin/bin have been on PATH setting always. Nothing changed.

Comment: Yes, but that means that changes to your Cygwin environment might leak into the Python execution. Remove cygwin/bin from PATH in a cmd shell, then run Python/pdb, see if that changes something. Also check if you have environment settings like PYTHON_PATH pointing to cygwin/ in you cmd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Re-installing python fixed it.

Comment: I am having the same issue and raised a question for this,

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48764584/no-command-history-in-python-repl-when-using-with-cygwin-under-windows-7 

Then I came across your post and tried your solution but sadly it didnt resolve my issue

Answer (score 3):

After installing package pyreadline, I was able to use up/down arrow keys to go through the command history.  readline does not install on Windows using pip, but pyreadline seems to be equivalent to it.

Answer (score 0):

Check the readline package, and its compatibility with your version of pdb. Maybe you have to downgrade.

EDIT:

As you were talking about newly installed packages on Cygwin, I was assuming that you are using Cygwin's Python. Hence my reference to Cygwin's readline package, as this might be influencing an existing Python installation.

Comment: I didn't have readline on Windows. History works on interactive python shell but not with pdb