# No command history in Python REPL when using with Cygwin under Windows 7

Tags: python, windows, cygwin, read-eval-print-loop

I am running Python v3.6.4 under Windows 7. My problem is that when I log into the Python repl (command line interpreter) from Cygwin I lose the history feature of Python. The up and down arrows dont show me the command history but actually move my cursor up and down the screen. When I try the same using the Windows Terminal (CMD) the behaviour is different - I can access the full Python command history. This CMD behaviour is preferable when writing blocks of Python code in the repl especially when you make a typo and need to re-enter the block.

Below are two screen shots showing this difference in behaviour. The first example shows the cursor is re-positioned up the screen. The second example shows the last command is retrieved which I can then use to edit

`example of REPL under Cygwin - up arrow moves cursor up screen`
[image]
`example of REPL under Windows Terminal (CMD) - up arrow retrieves last command history`
[image]

I stumbled across a similar issue
[Python pdb command history not working on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6348034/python-pdb-command-history-not-working-on-windows?rq=1)
and tried the suggested solution of re-installing Python but it didnt solve my issue.

Comment: winpty may help - https://github.com/rprichard/winpty

Comment: using python for cygwin under cygwin also